# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "_"

Tags: string, for-loop, input

I have problem bean method input
`p.hNo` and `p.sNo` are integer,

```
itemValue="#{util.encrypt(p.hNo+'_'+p.sNo)}"
```

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "_"

How can I append this string?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to concat integer to a string? You need to use String.valueOf(p.hNo) + '_'+String.valueOf(p.sNo)

Comment: it is same error for your solution.

#{bean.x+"_"+bean.y} not work